# Change Rosserial to connect to /dev/ttyS0

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How/where shall the connection for Rosserial - such that it doesn't tries to establish a serial over USB but across /dev/ttyS0 ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202757/change-rosserial-to-connect-to-/dev/ttys0/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `_port:=/dev/ttyUSB0` or similar.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1